# Using mailto in Instagram

Tags: instagram

Is there a way to format "mailto" links as http links? I'm trying to add a "mailto" to my Instagram bio.

Answer (score 1):

Instagram don't support clickable links posted in `Edit Profile->Bio` field. You can only put link to `Edit Profile->Website` field, but this not support `mailto`.

But you can switch your account from Creator type to Professional type.
Click on ☰ menu on in the upper right corner. Select `Settings->Account` and below you will see `Switch to Professional account` feature. Then add your mail address in the relevant settings.

Let's return to your account main page and you will see a new item above `Edit Profile` button:
`Promotions`, `Insights` and `Contact`

If you click on `Contact` you'll see subitems:
`Call` and `Email`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a website called https://mailxto.com , It lets you turn your mailto link into a short link (as HTTP link) and it can be used anywhere.